# Jsoup - CSS Select in DOM structure

Tags: dom, css-selectors, jsoup

I have got the following HTML:

```
some text <b>some bold text</b>
<span property='some property1>
some semantic term2</span> 
<p><span id='mark1'></span>
some text <i>some italic text</i></p>
<span property='some property2'>
some semantic term</span>
<span id='mark2'></span>
```

I would like to select all span elements with a 'property' attribute, which are placed between the span elements with ids 'mark1' and 'mark2' (these are my technical bookmarks, which should be then removed) and unwrap it.

I think the best way to implement it in Java Jsoup is to use the doc.select function. But I can't create the correct CSS query (I need something like: every span elements with property attribute BETWEEN these two elements).

The expected result (after removing the bookmarks):

```
  some text <b>some bold text</b>
    <span property='some property1>
    some semantic term2</span> 
    <p>
    some text <i>some italic text</i></p>
    some semantic term
```

Any ideas? Maybe something like E ~ F. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is only an example of course. I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: Will they all be at the same level? That is, be direct children of the same parent?

Comment: No - the positions are absolutely free. I will explain: I insert the bookmarks depending on a selection of the user in WYSIWYG editor. So he can select whatever he want. I am afraid there is no useable CSS query and I have to implement some awful recursion :-).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible: the Jsoup [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) is not expressive enough to select all tags between two arbitrarily-positioned tags.

However, you can use the [NodeTraverser](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeTraversor.html) class with a [NodeVisitor](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeVisitor.html) implementation that collects all elements visited between the two bookmark elements.  (This should be easier than "some awful recursion" referenced in your comment.)